# What is the simplest pluginManagement section on can add to a pom to get m2e and eclipse indigo to play together?

Tags: m2e

I have read the discussions on this topic but I don't see a simple solution.

Given the following really simple pom.xml, Indigo Eclipse and m2e (version 0.14.0.201107060316),  eclipse complains with

```
Multiple annotations found at this line
   - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources)
   - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-resources)
```

on

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myartifact</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
</project>
```

I know it has something to do with adding a  section as shown in http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered#execute_plugin_goal

I thought adding the following section to the pom.xml would clear at least one error, but it didn't so I must not have a clear understanding of what is wrong.

Any advice?  I'm sure this is simple for some of you.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myartifact</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>2.4.3</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>resources:resources</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute >
                                        <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute >
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem (Eclipse Indigo, Maven 3.0.2). I solved it following the steps indicated here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven

I installed the following features (use eclipse->Help->Install New Software):
- Maven Integration for Eclipse
- Maven Integration for WTP
from here:
http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp

Once I installed these features I update the project (rightclik on the project->Maven->Update project..). This worked for me. I hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks! Voted you up. Your tip helped me on Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler)